# Characterization of linear continuous functionals to judge on weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

We say that $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ in normed space $X$ when for any linear and continuous functional $f$ we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

I want to judge on weak convergence of sequence

$$\phi_n = (1, \frac 12, \frac13,...,\frac1n,0,0,...)$$

in $l^1$.

The hint I was given is to use characterization of linear and continuous functionals in $l^1$, i.e. I know that every linear and continuous functional in $l^1$ has to be in form $f(x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_na_n$ where $a_n \in l^\infty$ and $x_n \in l^1$ (we also know that $\|f\| = \|a_n\|_\infty$). But I'm not exactly sure how can I use this fact in juding on convergence of ($\phi_n$). I know that

$$f(\phi_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_na_n$$
where $a_n \in l^1$, but how exactly it implies the convergence/divergences ? Could you please give me a hint how I can apply this fact?

Comment: Try looking at the functional $(1,1,1,\ldots) \in \ell_{\infty}$ and see what that does to convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to check is whether there exists $(b_n) \in \ell^{1}$ such that $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac {a_k} k \to  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kb_k$ whenever $(a_n) \in \ell^{\infty}$. Taking $a_n=1$ for $n=j$ and $0$ for all other $j$ we get $b_j=\frac  1 j$ . This is true for all $j$. But then  $(b_n) \notin \ell^{1}$ so the given sequence does not converge weakly.

Comment: Why can you choose $(a_n)$ so arbitrary? I mean as I understand - you said that sequence $(1, \frac12, \frac13,...,\frac1n)$ has to be in form $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k}$, where $a_n \in l^\infty$. But it's not like that it's some specific $a_n$? Because your justification is based on choosing different $a_n$

Comment: I am proving by contradiction that the sequence cannot converge wealy. If it does converge weakly the limit condition in the first line of my answer must hold **for every** $(a_n)$. So I choose my $(a_n)$ suitably to arrive at a  contradction. @Lucian

Comment: Yes I understand your way of thinking, but I don't know why it's proper. Because if functional is linear and continuous then its in form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_n a_n$ for $\textbf{some specific}$ $a_n$, and you are treating as it was $\textbf{for all}$ $a_n$

Comment: Convergence is is for every continuous linear functional

Comment: And every bounded sequence corresponds to a continuous linear functional. @Lucian